# How to preserve matrix variable when saving data frame in R

Tags: r, csv, matrix

I have the data frame with 3 variables in R:

```
 str(mydata)

'data.frame':   975 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ productSelect: int [1:975, 1:7] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ unitsSold    : int  406 635 406 635 406 616 358 616 406 616 ...
 $ profit       : int  346 435 346 435 346 416 318 416 346 416 ...
```

`productSelect` is a matrix.

I want to save this data frame to a file and then retrieve it with the same 3 variables. However, when I write and then read this data frame, it has 9 variables:

```
write.csv(mydata, file = "mydata.csv", row.names = FALSE)
df = read.csv("mydata.csv")
str(df)

'data.frame':   975 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ productSelect.1: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ productSelect.2: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 ...
 $ productSelect.3: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ productSelect.4: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 ...
 $ productSelect.5: int  1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ productSelect.6: int  1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ productSelect.7: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ unitsSold      : int  406 635 406 635 406 616 358 616 406 616 ...
 $ profit         : int  346 435 346 435 346 416 318 416 346 416 ...
```

Is there any quick way to write and read a data frame so that the variable productSelect will stay in the matrix form?

Comment: See `save`, `saveRDS`

Comment: Save it as an R item.    save(mydata.RData)